# How to use scikit-learn to classify text

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to classify two text by using scikit-learn. But I want to extract features by myself. Just like using `stop_words='english'` to stop word list for English is used on *CountVectorizer*. How to set my own word list to let *CountVectorizer* to count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own list of stop words to the stop_words argument in the CountVectorizer and it will not count the words that you don't want it to be counted in your input text in scikit-learn.
For example, if I don't want words such as "cat", "dog" and "elephant" to use as tokens, I would instantiate CountVectorizer as the following:

```
CountVectorizer(stop_words=['cat','dog', elephant'])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Do you know how to choose words? For example I only want  words such as "apple", "banana". what should I do?

Comment: You can use the vocabulary argument of the CountVectorizer class. For example: CountVectorizer(vocabulary={'apple':0,'banana':1})

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helps me a lot

Comment: If it was helpful, please give an upvote to the answer and help the community